# Open Internet Explorer from Google Chrome using a or button tag or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

My website is built to run on Chrome, I need to add a tag or button that will open an Internet Explorer window.

It would be even better if I could open Internet Explorer to a login page; Is there a way to auto-populate the user name and password?

I’m developing in PHP and jQuery.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way of doing this. Maybe you can tell us what you're trying to do so we can suggest you some alternatives?

Comment: if your web site is built to work only one one browser then you are doing it WRONG.

Comment: It is conceivable that there is a valid use for this functionality; after all IE has some pretty unique integration of it's own (ActiveX, VBA, Custom BHOs, etc.) that may be part of a bigger picture, especially in a corporate environment that needs a high level of automation and is looking to reduce support costs. I think this is actually a pretty good question.

Comment: This is a good question. Some legacy enterprise apps only run inside of IE. I'm in a corporate environment that frowns on other browsers besides IE because they have one or two applications that require it. If I could launch IE from Chrome or Firefox only when needed it would allow us to move forward quicker.

Answer (score 7):

Not possible, sorry. Web sites can not launch applications of their choosing.

If you controlled the environment, you could [register an application for a custom protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that launches IE.

Comment: I control the environment, could you explain how to do it?

Comment: No you don't. For security reasons you are confined to a tab. Why do you want to launch IE? A site that is IE only?

Comment: @Itsik: I added a link to my answer.

Comment: I would like to log in from within my website into other web site (not of mine) that is working only on IE

Comment: Sorry, unless you do some nasty handler application that the client must download and install you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, the only way this is even going to possible is if your users are willing to jump through some pretty serious hoops. Here is one possible method:

1. You would need to create an AIR application that utilizes AIR's NativeProcess class to launch Internet Explorer. (Reference: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) It will need to support brower invocation. (Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e19)
2. Create a SWF file that can be embedded on the page to loaded, that launches and installs the AIR application if necessary. (Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e15.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a640a-7ff8)

Please note that the initial launch will require a number of click-throughs. Once the AIR application has been installed the first time though, calling the AIR application, which in turn will launch the native process you want will happen pretty quiet seamlessly.

This sounds pretty convoluted, but if you have Flash Professional/Flash Builder, the code required is pretty minimal. I'm sure with a little bit of Googling there is is probably some pre-packaged examples that will take care of most of this. (The references include code for the SWF that launches the AIR application, and for AIR application that launches your native process, Internet Explorer)

I know this is a bit of overkill, but hopefully this is beneficial to anyone who wants to execute native processes from the browser in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, however you could suggest they install [IETab](http://www.ietab.net/home) and use it for the linked site.